# Ruby on Rails + jQuery Mobile + phonegap - All server side HTML rendering - Will it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, jquery-mobile, server-side

In an attempt to be able to create a rich application using ROR3 Jquery Mobile and phonegap after reading this article - http://fuelyourcoding.com/getting-started-with-jquery-mobile-rails-3/

I was wondering if it would be possible to render all of the apps content on the server side while jquery mobile handled all of the nice transitions?

Would the work as a phonegap app? (considering that no JSON is being used at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use ROR with jQM, no problem there. jQM will be used only to handle a HTML GUI restyling. But you are not going to have transitions with an ajax turned off.

Then again this should not worry you because transitions don't work well with the older Android platform's. Even versions 4+ have a few problems.

And yes, this app will work with phonegap, as I said previously just without transitions.

**EDIT :**

If you still want to use ajax (it can be done) you will only have a problem with form submitting.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the quick response.
The main concern is that it will not be accepted to the AppStore because all the HTMLs are on the server, so basically the application doesn't contain any code other than the URL of the server and phonegap wrap.

Comment: Yes this is a problem for the Apple store, they will not accept your app. I had a problem with the Apple app store and my last jQM app. It took me 2 months of constant mailing to have it published (and I had a single html multi page app without any server side code).

Comment: Thanks again... any tips on how to get it accepted? What do you suggest to do? use a JS MV* ? such as backbone or Angular (which would you choose?)

Comment: If you ask for my opinion then always (and always :) ) AngularJS. It is my subjective opinion. I have tested both of them. Both of them are good, but backbone feels like a lightweight version of AngularJS. And from tips, before you use any phonegap plugin google it to find is it allowed by Apple. My problem was 3rd party plugin for PayPal. I thought I could cheat Apple, finally it cost me money and time.

Comment: MVC wont help you if you generate you code on the server side. If possible create a predefined jQM app (in this case use the backbone, I naver had luck with the jQM + AngulaJS) and use ajax to load only dynamic data.

Comment: But my final advice, if possible create a native app :) . When I was starting with hybrid app's I didn't know I would spent so much time debugging them and finding workarounds and fixes. I nearly went mad with jQM. Now I'm only helping people with jQM. I went native ;)

Comment: If you have any more questions about a jQM, feel free to ask me directly. My email is in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

It will certainly work, proof is my example *rails* / *ember.js* Application that is exported with *Phonegap*. It comes with token authentication (ember-auth) + OAuth (Google, LinkedIn,..) and *Devise*.

See it in de the devel branch of my base App project: https://github.com/joscas/base_app/tree/devel

Life deploy: https://starter-app-staging.herokuapp.com (the desktop version)

It uses a gem ([phonegap-rails](https://github.com/joscas/phonegap-rails)) I've created to export assets, fix paths etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can actually render everything server side and have it still work. This is how basecamp does it, using turbolinks, and how we're attempting to do it. GoNative.io handles this all for you, but you can also just create a webpage in phonegap that just opens an external URL to your site (the user can't tell). I don't see this on their docs but we've done it and it works. There are a few issues with file upload and the UI which are solvable, but GoNative.io claims to do it all for you while handing those. We originally did ours using PhoneGap, which probably would have worked but ended up switch to GoNative. There may be an issue with getting into apple store using this method, but we're being optimistic that we can get in (GoNative.io claim to have no problem with it)